# Getting file not found error in Phython Windows

Tags: path, absolute

Using the below code gives me file not found error -

```
with open("/Users/Subhajit/Desktop/Subhajit.txt","r") as my_file:
    content = my_file.read()
    print(content)
```

but the file is present in - `C:\Users\Subhajit\Desktop`

Please help

Tried to fetch the file data but getting file not found issue